# SSRS: How do you get the current value in a secondary dataset beyond the FIRST() or LAST()?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a singular tablix linked to `DatasetA` and additional secondary `DatasetB`. Both Datasets from the associated stored procedures produce multiple rows. 
When writing expressions to `DatasetA` I can simply use the `Fields!fieldname.Value` syntax and I get multiple tablixs instances just fine reflecting the various returned row data.

My question is how do I write expressions to DatasetB to do the same?

I dont just want the `First()` value or just the `Last()` value, I want the current value....? 
I cannot simply write `(Fields!fieldname.Value, "DatasetName")` so that each tablix reflects the current value of each returned field from `DatasetB` so what do i do?

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but I just cant work it out....

Comment: [Report Builder Functions - Lookup Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function) might do the trick.

Comment: Like R. Richards mentioned one option would be a Lookup function. Another option might be a sub report.